# Foreach changes not being preserved on Linq item collection

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, loops

In the following example, changes applied in the foreach are not preserved when I return the collection:

```
var people = SomeLinqToSqlSource();

foreach (var person in people)
{
   person.Name = "Jimmy";
}

return people.AsQueryable();
```

This contradicts my understanding that within a foreach(..), you operate by-reference on the current item.

Could anybody please let me know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `people` is an `IQueryable` and is re-queried when you return it and the consumer enumerates the results - your updated properties are gone now, since each `person` instance is reconstructed by executing the query.

If you want to preserve changes you have to materialize your data first, i.e. using `ToList()` and then return the list as an `IEnumerable` (or `IList`)

Comment: Thanks! I understand now. I've materialized my data - all working now.