# Foreach item changes not preserved outside loop

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, parallel-processing, persistence

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742937/foreach-changes-not-being-preserved-on-linq-item-collection) already but it does not explain it so that I understand what is actually going on.  I've been developing for years and never come across this before (though my usage of Linq and Parallel is fairly recent).

My code is:

```
Parallel.ForEach(databaseMetadata.Rows.Cast<DataRow>(), row => {
        var fieldName = row.Item("Name", "");
        var field = this.Fields.Where(f => f.Name.ToLower() == fieldName.ToLower()).SingleOrDefault();
        if(field != null) { field.Validate(this, connection, row); }
});
```

Within the field.Validate function it sets a property named 'HasBeenValidated' on the field object to true, however, as soon as I come out of this Parallel.ForEach loop, that property is set back to false.  Can someone please explain why this is happening and what I can do to ensure that changes within the loops are persisted outside of the loop.

Edited:

Below is a copy of the code in field.Validate:

```
internal void Validate(EntityAttribute entity, SqlConnection connection, [AllowNull] DataRow metadata) {
    this.HasBeenValidated = true;
    var isRequired = this.IsRequired;
    var maxLength = this.MaxLength;
    var isAutoGenerated = this.IsAutoGenerated;
    var dataType = this.member.PropertyType;
    var dataTypeAsString = "";
    if(metadata != null) {
        isRequired = metadata.Item("IsRequired", false);
        maxLength = metadata.Item("MaxLength", 0);
        isAutoGenerated = metadata.Item("IsAutoGenerated", false);
        dataTypeAsString = metadata.Item("DataType", "");
        if(dataTypeAsString == this.member.PropertyType.ToSqlServerDataType()) { dataTypeAsString = ""; }
    } else {
        dataTypeAsString = this.member.PropertyType.ToSqlServerDataType();
    }
    if(metadata == null || isRequired != this.IsRequired || maxLength != this.MaxLength || isAutoGenerated != this.IsAutoGenerated || dataTypeAsString != "") {
        var sql = string.Format((metadata == null ? "ALTER TABLE [{0}].[{1}] ADD" : "ALTER TABLE {0} ALTER COLUMN"), entity.Schema, entity.Name) + " " + this.Sql + ";";
        if(!connection.ExecuteCommand(sql, 1)) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to create or alter column '" + this.Name + "' on table '" + entity.Name + "'.");
        }
    }
}
```

The HasBeenValidated property is defined on the field object as:

```
internal bool HasBeenValidated { get; set; }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I presume there are no value types in play here? Other than the bool property obviously. Have you tried changing this to a normal `foreach` and stepping through?

Comment: You're asking us to comment when we can't see `Validate(...)`, can't see where the data is coming from (i.e. is it a repeatable lists? or is `.Rows` actually querying the data again), can't see where you're checking `HasBeenValidated` (or where it gets set), and can't see whether this is a `struct` vs `class` issue. We might *assume* that `DataRow` means this is `DataTable`, but even that assumption is unsound... Additionally, note that `DataTable` does not claim to be thread-safe for write operations, although it would be speculation to suggest that this was related.

Comment: aka: do you have a repeatable example we can actually see?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth and DarenThomas: I will change it to a for loop and see what happens.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I have included the code for Validate.  Rows is actually coming from a data table.  The HasBeenValidated is a simple property on the fields object, which I have included in the edit on my question. There are no structs at all in this code, they are all classes.  I'm not writing any data to the datatable in this code so thread-safety is not an issue (with respect to datatable writes anyway).

Comment: @Maintex you are, presumably, updating each `DataRow`, though, right? i.e. setting a field to `true` or `false`? That is sufficient to break it: see my example.

Comment: @MarcGravell Nope, the point of this code is to read the row (which contains metadata about fields in a table) compare the row data with the metadata stored against the field (which is an custom attribute class stored in a list if that makes a difference?) and if the metadata is different, it is supposed to alter the column in the database to match the metadata stored in the field attribute class.

Comment: @Maintex with that extra info, I've deleted my answer; however, I think you're just going to have to debug it. A bool won't become false by itself. First things to check: was the method **actually** called, i.e. did the field name match.

Comment: Sorry all, I've figured out the problem, it has to do with me calling the GetCustomAttributes in the Linq statement that populates the this.Fields list.  My sincere apologies to all.  I do have a post answering and explaining it in more detail but I can't post it yet due to lack of rep.  Really sorry to all and thanks for your efforts and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies if I've wasted anyone's time but I have figured out the cause of this issue.  The this.Fields list is an IEnumerable<> of the field type which is queryable.  I thought that this would be better than having a greedy list (since this class has a good number of lists on it).  The code for generating the Fields list is:

```
this.Fields = allProperties
    .Select(property => new { Property = property, Field = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault() as FieldAttribute })
    .Where(info => info.Field != null && (info.Field as ListAttribute) == null)
    .Select(info => { info.Field.Member = info.Property; return info.Field; });
```

What I completely failed to realise was that GetCustomAttributes, rather unexpectedly (from my point of view anyway) regenerates a copy of the attribute class each time it is called.

Had this been a simpler class I might have suspected this sooner, but I was also changing properties in the fields class when setting the Member property (i.e. extracting metadata from the info.Property and setting properties within the field class based on the properties of that class) so when I was looking at the field class in the debugger I could see a lot of the properties had been changed (which mislead me to think it was the same instance of the field class and not a copy).

I really apologise if I've wasted anyone's time and effort in this but hopefully by posting my mistake this can help other people in future who might stumble using the GetCustomAttribute in a similar way inside a non-greedy Linq expression.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a synchronization problem with your `DataRow` objects - are you sure `field.Validate` doesn't update the property in the database? And that your `databaseMetadata` isn't just still sitting on the old data?

The arguments `connection, row` to `field.Validate` suggest you might be doing something like that...

Try to use a normal `for` loop and see what happens. Do you have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you call databaseMetadata.Rows twice and check is it the same instance or different one.

```
bool isEquals = ReferenceEquals(databaseMetadata.Rows, databaseMetadata.Rows)
```

If it's doesn't support immutability I expect it to return a copy of rows each time you access Rows property.